# Pass through NextJS frontend requests to NextJS API first and then to Rails API or directly to Rails APi?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, next.js, rails-api

I am developing an App which consists of a `NextJS` frontend and a `Rails API` backend.

There is this `/api` route from NextJS where I can put "server side code".
Should I use this feature by sending my frontend requests first to that `/api` endpoint and **then** to the Rails API endpoint or is "ok" to directly send the requests to the Rails API endpoint?

For me that looks a bit like a "jump around the corner".

Are there true benefits using the `NextJS frontend -> NextJS API -> Rails API` approach?

Comment: no need for NextJS API, you can use API calls on the page.
document: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages

Comment: `/api` allows you to build and  expose apis, if you already have apis, just cosume them wherever you want. (NextJS frontend ->  Rails API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

From next js docs:

> #### Use Cases
>
> For new projects, you can build your entire API with API Routes. **If
> you have an existing API, you do not need to forward calls to the API
> through an API Route.**
> Some other use cases for API
>
> Routes are:
>
> - Masking the URL of an external service (e.g. /api/secret instead of https://company.com/secret-url)
> - Using Environment Variables on the server to securely access external services.
>   https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction#use-cases

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction#use-cases

Answer (score 0):

The /api route in Next.js is primarily intended to create serverless functions that can be called directly from the frontend. It allows you to create endpoints that can execute server-side code without the need for a dedicated server or backend.

However, in your case, since you already have a Rails API backend, it might be more straightforward to make requests directly to the Rails API endpoint from your Next.js frontend. This approach can simplify your architecture and reduce unnecessary hops between servers.  [Read more](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)

Using the Next.js frontend -> Next.js API -> Rails API approach can add extra complexity to your application and potentially introduce more points of failure. It might be useful if you need to perform some additional processing or manipulation of the data before sending it to the Rails API endpoint. However, if you don't need this additional processing, it might be best to avoid using the Next.js API route.